# Spring boot google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot

I am currently building a web application using Spring boot. I am looking for good tutorials that can help me integrate google App engine services with my app and also tutorials on how to configure my application for deploying it on Google App engine.

Thanks !

Comment: spring boot on app engine may not be the best of ideas since the whole bootstrapping process for new instances can be very slow using spring, it may even exceed the 60 second request deadline, so your warumup request may never get answered properly. If dependency injection is the only thing you're looking for I can recommend dagger (http://square.github.io/dagger/).

Comment: actually I have few Spring based project on App Engine, and I don't see much problems with startup time. for relatively large app i was forced to use F2 instance, but in general it works fine with standard F1